# Any one know how to remove this shared chrome instance?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, sharing

This keeps popping up and showing current tabs from a colleague's computer. Any way to disable this? It may be because we're using a global apple ID but unsure.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the handoff functionality. Which is indeed linked to an AppleID. You can easily disable handoff in System Preferences.

```
System Preferences --> General
```

And then uncheck “Allow Handoff Between This Mac and Your iCloud Devices”.

[image]

More info on handoff at the Apple's website [Pick up where you left off with Handoff on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/hand-off-between-devices-mchl732d3c0a/mac).

Comment: Note that this fix also prevents handoff of anything else from any other device.